# Django model for a legacy table containing a custom data type

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, custom-data-type

I am working with a Postgresql legacy table and found that some fields have *custom* data types.

For example, instead of e.g. `character varying`, the column `color` has `color_type` as data type, with permissible options `[red|green|blue|black]`.

Relying on the `inspectdb` command, the automatically generated model contains the following line and comment:

```
color = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
```

I would "clean" this line as described in the following class, but am not sure a) if it will properly "fit" the existing table (e.g. if I write new objects inside the table), and b) whether if migrated to a new database, the custom_type would be correctly reproduced:

```
class Things(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True) 

    RED = 'red'
    GREEN = 'green'
    BLUE = 'blue'
    BLACK= 'black'
    COLOR_CHOICES = (
                      (RED, 'red'),
                      (GREEN, 'green'),
                      (BLUE, 'blue'),
                      (BLACK, 'black'),
                     )
    color = models.CharField(       
                               max_length = 10, 
                               choices = COLOR_CHOICES,
                               default = RED, 
                               null = True, 
                               blank = True
                            )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'myuser'
```

What is the proper way to reflect this custom data type in the Django model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [Custom Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-database-types) which uses a custom defined database type:

```
class ColorField(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'enum("red","green","blue","black")'
```

Comment: Thanks, missed that part in the docs! Could you also please clarify if I could safely write `color = ColorField(null = True,  blank = True)`, i.e. passing conventional arguments to the custom field class?

Comment: Yes you can, the common field options availabe to all field types are listed here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#field-options